# UIView. How Do I Find the Root SuperView Fast?

Tags: ios, uiview, subview, superview

I have a random child view in a view hierarchy. What is the best/fastest/cleverest way to get to the root superview?

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your app only has one `UIWindow` (usually true), and if that window's only subview is your root controller's view (also usually true):

`[randomChildView.window.subviews objectAtIndex:0]`

Or you could recursively climb out of the hierarchy, by checking `view.superview` until you find a view whose superview is `nil`.

Comment: You may want to double check that you will ever find that a "superview is nil"  I tried that and got stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: The alternate of climbing only takes a few insignificant processor cycles, and you don't need to assume anything. I don't get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 12):

It's an insignificant amount of processor time to go straight up the superview hierarchy. I have this in my UIView category.

```
- (UIView *)rootView {
    UIView *view = self;
    while (view.superview != Nil) {
        view = view.superview;
    }
    return view;
}
```

swift3/4:

```
func rootSuperView() -> UIView
{
    var view = self
    while let s = view.superview {
        view = s
    }
    return view
}
```

Comment: Your method always returns `self.window`

Comment: No, it will find the highest UIView element in the hierarchy. Of course if you only run it on views that are under self.window it will only return self.window.

Answer (score 1):

I like this one.

```
extension UIView {
    func rootView() -> UIView {
        return superview?.rootView() ?? superview ?? self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast solution (fast as in minimalist):

```
extension UIView {
    var rootView: UIView {
        superview?.rootView ?? self
    }
}
```